# load_earley not available in nltk 3.0

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to reproduce an example from the NLTK text book - http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/kit/2009s/clt231/NLTK/book/ch10-AnalyzingTheMeaningOfSentences.html

However, while running this example :

```
>>> from nltk.parse import load_earley
>>> cp = load_earley('grammars/book_grammars/sql0.fcfg')
>>> query = 'What cities are located in China'
>>> trees = cp.nbest_parse(query.split())
>>> answer = trees[0].node['sem']
>>> q = ' '.join(answer)
>>> print q
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name load_earley
```

Is load_earley discontinued? If so, I am not able to find the replacement for it. Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I got the updated course work -> http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html

The above code translates into

```
>>>from nltk import load_parser
>>> cp = load_parser('grammars/book_grammars/sql0.fcfg')
>>> query = 'What cities are located in China'
>>> trees = list(cp.parse(query.split()))
>>> answer = trees[0].label()['SEM']
>>> answer = [s for s in answer if s]
>>> q = ' '.join(answer)
>>> print(q)
```

load_earley is replaced by load_parser

```
>>> trees = cp.nbest_parse(query.split())
>>> answer = trees[0].node['sem']
```

is replaced by

```
>>> trees = list(cp.parse(query.split()))
>>> answer = trees[0].label()['SEM']
>>> answer = [s for s in answer if s]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that is the case, I ran into the same issue. That course uses NLTK version 2.0. Also:

`The material presented in this book assumes that you are using Python version 2.4 or 2.5`